python telegram bot job queue on start-up
I am using async version of python-telegram-bot lib 20+
persistence = PicklePersistence(filepath="pickle_persistence")
application = Application.builder().token(token).persistence(persistence).build()

application.job_queue.run_daily(task_function, time=time(hour=3, minute=0))

but in debuger i see than .job_queue exist but it is None
seems like it's not init or something, can't find examples or docs how to add some daily job on startup in async version of library
in older versions of python-telegram-bot it was like this:
updater = Updater(settings.TOKEN)
updater.job_queue.run_repeating(task_function, interval=7 * 60, first=0)


In order to use the JobQueue, you'll have to install PTB with an optional dependency:
pip install "python-telegram-bot[job-queue]"
See also the readmes section on dependencies in PTB.
